# How to lock individual methods in a common utility class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I have written the following code:

```
public class ClassLevelSynchronization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new AddThread()).start();
        new Thread(new MultiplyThread()).start();
    }
}

class UtilityCalculator{
    private static final Object ADD_LOCK = new Object();
    private static final Object MULTIPLY_LOCK = new Object();

    public static int add(int op1, int op2){
        synchronized (ADD_LOCK) {
            return op1+op2;
        }       
    }

    public static int multiply(int op1, int op2){
        synchronized (MULTIPLY_LOCK) {
            return op1*op2;
        }       
    }
}

class AddThread implements Runnable{
    public void run() {     
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Addition of: "+i+" + "+(i+1)+" = "+UtilityCalculator.add(i, i+1));
            }   
    }
}

class MultiplyThread implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Multiplication of: "+i+" * "+(i+1)+" = "+UtilityCalculator.multiply(i, i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

How do I ensure that the objects of `AddThread` and `MultiplyThread` can acquire locks for `add(int op1, int op2)` and `multiply(int op1, int op2)` methods respectively at the same time without blocking out each other?

In other words, I want to ensure that the two methods of `UtilityCalculator` class can be used simultaneously by two threads at any given time. How do I achieve this? Am I missing anything in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already done it - you're synchronizing on different objects, so it should be fine. Is there some reason you suspect this isn't working?

To make it more obvious that it *is* working, put a sleep for a second inside each of the synchronization blocks. Your program will still execute all 20 operations in about 10 seconds, showing that the threads aren't blocking each other.

Comment: Actually, I do not understand that when I write the following statement: UtilityCalculator.add(i, i+1); how does it acquire the lock for addition and more importantly why does it not also acquire the lock for multiplication and thus block out the other thread???

Comment: @n_g: That statement itself doesn't acquire the lock - the synchronized block inside the `add` method does. Multiple threads could get *just inside* the `add` method at the same time, but only one of them will get inside the synchronized block at any one time.

Answer (score 2):

Those two methods *already* use two different objects to synchronize on, so you *already can* call and execute `add` and `multiply` at the same time from different threads.

Also, I assume you know this, but I have to add it, just to be sure: those method don't *need* any synchronization as all, as they are inherently thread-safe. If the actual code is just for demonstration, then feel free to ignore this.

Comment: Thanks Joachim!!! Yes, the code is for demo only. But you say that the methods are inherently thread safe. How is that?

Comment: By saying 'these methods are thread-safe', he means that the methods, dont change the state of the parent object, and thus have no side effect. These are also called Re-entrant methods:  A reentrant method would be one that can safely be entered, even when the same method is in progress, further up the call stack (of the same thread). A non-reentrant method would not be safe to use in that way.